# Bind the button of razorview with controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor-pages

I need to bind such button :

```
 <button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Compress", "Home")'" />
```

with such controller action :

```
 public void Compress()
    {
        _compressingService.CompressAllFiles();
    }
```

the service CompressAllFiles(); don't get the value, it is just do compressing files in server.
that is why me controller method is void, but pressing this button i have:`System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` exception. what's wrong? may be i'm wrong bind it or my signature of controller action is not valid? thank you

Comment: have you instantiated `_compressingService`?

Comment: no, i'm not, it works now, thanks Tom

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

The exception `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` is thrown because you are trying to access an object that is null. In this case, it is `_compressingService` which will either need instantiating or injecting